# Uniform Integrability and relation to $L^p$ for $p>1$

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, martingales, supremum-and-infimum, uniform-integrability

Let $X_n$ be a martingale.

Then we know that for $p> 1$ the conditions

$\sup_n E[|X_n|^p] < \infty$ and $E[\sup_n |X_n|^p] < \infty$ are equivalent.

For $p=1$ this does not hold, because uniform integrability is stronger than the first and weaker than the second condition.

But my question is: Are the conditions for $p>1$ also equivalent when $X_n$ is not a martingale but arbitrary?

Comment: **Example:** Suppose the $X_n$ are i.i.d. with $\Bbb E[|X_1|^p]<\infty$ for some $p>1$ but $\Bbb P[|X_1|>x]>0$ for all $x>0$.

Comment: Thank you for the example. I am not completely sure how to deal with it but I suppose that this should be an example showing that for non-martingales the conditions are *not* equivalent. So of course we have $\sup_n E[|X_n|^p] < \infty$ then. But I do not really see how to get from $E[ \sup_n |X_n|^p]$ to $P[|X_1|>x]$, can you give me a further hint?

Comment: If $\Bbb P[|X_1|>x]>0$ then by Borel-Cantelli, $\Bbb P[|X_n|>x$ i.o. $]=1$, which implies that $\Bbb P[\sup_n|X_n|>x]=1$ for all $x>0$. In short, $\Bbb P[\sup_n|X_n|=+\infty]=1$ for this example.

Answer (score 1):

As John Dawkins explained in the comments, we may have $\sup_n\mathbb E\left|X_n\right|^p<\infty$ but $\sup_{n}|X_n|=+\infty$ almost surely when $(X_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is an independent identically distributed sequence such that $\mathbb E\left|X_1\right|^p$ is finite and $\mathbb P\{|X_1|\gt x\}\gt 0$ for any $x$.

However, if $X_n=\left(\sum_{j=1}^nY_j/n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ where $Y_j$ is a strictly stationary sequence, then for $p\gt 1$, $\sup_n\mathbb E|X_n|^p\lt \infty$ means that $\mathbb E\left|Y_1\right|^p$ which implies, by the maximal ergodic theorem, that $\sup_n|X_n|^p$ is integrable.